# Time triggered web job Scheduler start only after running it manually

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have created a Time triggered web job and after deploying it I need to run it manually for the first time. After the manual start, it run at a specified interval.

Is it possible scheduler start without clicking on run button?

Comment: Provide the approach you have tried.

Comment: ProcessQueueMessage([TimerTrigger("%ScheduleAppSetting%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timer)

I have specified cron expression 0 */30 * * * *  it run on every 30 minute but after starting it manually

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible scheduler start without clicking on run button?
```

After reproducing issue from my side AFAIK ,
In webjob we need to run it manually for the first time after the manual start, it run at a specified interval.
But if you want to run it manually with out clicking on RUN it is possible in logicapps.
If you are okay with the **alternative method** try to follow the below steps of **logic App**.
1.Created Web jobs in App service as expected it is running after clicking on refresh or Run buttons
[image]
2. So for manual trigger of webjob followed the [document](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5248640/Create-Deploy-Webjobs-and-Schedule-Using-Azure-Log) and created logicapp and got the espected results.
3. Created logicapp workflow as shown below .
Here taking Recurrence trigger it runs every 3 minutes.You can change the interval and frequency based on your requirement
[image]

4.Next taking HTTP action in HTTP action fill the below details

Method: POST

URI: Web job URL

Authentication type: Basic

Username

Password
[image]
In appservice select the webjob and click on properties there you will get URL ,USER NAME and PASSWORD as shown in below image.

[image]

Then click on SAVE and RUN the trigger then it automatically runs based on the schedule.
Logic App ran successfully as shown below
[image]

In overview look for Run history for the results. Now the application would trigger the webjobs as per the schedule.
As shown in runhistory based on my interval it runs once in every three minutes.
[image]

Also try to [refer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#timertrigger) this

Comment: Thanks, vijaya for your reply. I will discuss this with the team but Thanks for your efforts.